# Should I use Appcelerator Titanium for development of my application?

Tags: android, ios, titanium

I need to develop quite simple application for Android and iPhone (development will be done on Windows 7) - it should download 100 questions from the database, then user offline answers the question, then answers should be uploaded back to the server with next synchronization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Titanium would probably work well for a simple application like the one you described.  I do see one issue however which is even using titanium you can not build iOS apps on a windows machine.  Titanium still uses the Xcode tool chain which is only available on a Mac.